# How to get Python clear-text plugin auth working on Windows (using MySQLdb)?

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, mysql-python

I have a MariaDB 5.5.57-1ubuntu0.14.04.1 installed on Ubuntu Linux 14.04 and configured with the following to authenticate MySQL users using our OpenLDAP infrastructure via PAM:

```
# cat /etc/mysql/conf.d/ldap.cnf 
[mysqld]
pam-use-cleartext-plugin
plugin-load = auth_pam.so

# cat /etc/mysql/conf.d/ssl.cnf  
[mysqld]
ssl-cipher = DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/ssl/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/ssl/server-key.pem
```

I've created my user in mysql like this:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE user 'ldap1'@'%' IDENTIFIED VIA pam;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'ldap1'@'%' IDENTIFIED VIA pam  REQUIRE SSL;
```

I can authenticate from a remote Linux host doing this:

```
mysql -u ldap1 -p -h my.server.net --ssl --enable-cleartext-plugin
```

When I connect from MySQL Workbench on Windows 7 I can tick 'Enable Cleartext Authentication Plugin' under the Advanced tab (Require SSL of course) and authenticate as well there too.
[image]

When I run my Python script, I get the error message below. Anyone know a fix or is there a DLL I need to install?

*NOTE*:The code I'm using was sent to me from an outside developer and not so sure I can share the code so just posting the error output. If this is not a common problem with a known workaround (It's been difficult finding all the right pieces to do this from both Linux and Windows platforms) I can certainly email said developer and ask about posting watered down version of the connect routine. The code *does* import `MySQLdb` to establish the DB connection if it matters.

[image]